# OWASP ZAP export to CSV?

Tags: owasp, zap

Simon (et al),
There is a tool I would like to use, Neuralys but it only takes CSV and NESSUS inputs natively, is there a way to convert a ZAP report into a CSV file?
Thanks
--joe

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's a bit complicated. You can use the [API](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiGen_core) (`xmlreport` \ `jsonreport`) to generate XML or JSON report, and convert from XML/JSON to CSV. Look like there are a few tools out there, like [this](https://json-csv.com/xml) that can help with converting from XML to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to create a script - that way you can output the alerts in any format you like :)
We have a simple script for looping through the alerts here: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/blob/master/standalone/Loop%20through%20alerts.js